# How to read data from Foursquare via its API to rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth, foursquare

Using omniauth and devise, I managed to run with foursquare API to create users. But right now, I can read no data about the user from Foursquare and save them to database. This code is working only for logging in without password right now. I cannot read anything from 4square.

What I want to do is, reading the user's data from foursquare such as firstname, lastname, profile photo and so on and save them to database.

My controller:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      flash.notice = "Signed in!"
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
  alias_method :foursquare, :all
end
```

User model:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.username = auth.id
      user.name = auth.info.firstName
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    if session["devise.user_attributes"]
      new(session["devise.user_attributes"], without_protection: true) do |user|
        user.attributes = params
        user.valid?
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?
  end

  def update_with_password(params, *options)
    if encrypted_password.blank?
      update_attributes(params, *options)
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

Any help is very wellcome. Thankss..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use a gem such as this one, which allows you to get the data you are looking for from the API https://github.com/mattmueller/foursquare2